# SQL Case When Repeating Conditions

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, case

I have a table called country that has 2 columns: *orderid, country_code*.

I need to do the following CASE WHEN:

```
SELECT 
    CASE
    WHEN country_code IN ('PT','IT','ES','PL','AD') THEN 'SWE'
    WHEN country_code IN ('MD','BG','BA','SI','HR','ME','RO','RS') THEN 'SEE'
    WHEN country_code IN ('CI','GH','MA','NG','UG','KE','TN') THEN 'AFRICA'
    WHEN country_code IN ('CI','GH','NG','UG','KE','TN') THEN 'SSA' 
    WHEN country_code IN ('UA','BY','GE','KZ','KG','AM') THEN 'ECA'
    END AS region,
    COUNT(DISTINCT orderid) AS amount_of_orders
FROM country
GROUP BY 1
```

However, when I run the code, Region SSA doesn't appear because the tcondition before (AFRICA) is using the countries of SSA *(SSA is the same as AFRICA but without MA)*.

How can I achieve to have the complete amount of orders for AFRICA and SSA?

rdbms: Amazon Redshift

**EDIT:**
This is my table right now:

```
SWE 200
SEE 500
AFRICA 350
SSA 0 <--- (it doesn't appear because the conditions were met by AFRICA region)
ECA 200
```

And I need the following:

```
SWE 200
SEE 500
AFRICA 350 --> (MA represent 150 orders)
SSA 200 --> (sames as AFRICA, but without MA)
ECA 200
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: What exactly is the result supposed to look like? Do you want one column per region with TRUE/FALSE? Or only one column with a list (e.g. 'AFRICA,SSA') or what else?

Comment: I suppose you mean the amount of orders per region *list*, as a result row shows a list, the amount of orders should refer to that list, right?

Comment: Or maybe you rather want one row per region, i.e. for your example one row for 'AFRICA' and one row for 'SSA', each with its order count? (That would mean, though, that you could not add up the regions' order counts, as one order could be counted in multiple orders.)

Comment: Please edit your question to provide an example of some inputs and the outputs you would like to see for those inputs.

Comment: Done! I Edit with my actual table and the table I want.

Comment: And you have thus changed your original request fundamentally from "column with a region list" to "one row per region". Next time please show the expected result right away. (Or at least don't give a wrong answer when asked what the result shall look like.) I have updated my answer with a solution, but I would actually rather suggest that you add a region table and a region_country table to your database instead of hiding the relations in a query.

Comment: Another side note: I hope your real table is not called `country` when it is not a table with one row per country. It is some order table obviously, but not the main order table with one row per order (for in that case you would not need a *distinct* count of order IDs). So it is probably some form of an order detail table and should be named appropriately. Please note that such misnomers can make your request harder to understand, while in real live you can get maintanance problems (mainly inadequate queries with undesired results for instance).

Comment: Thorsten, I'm sorry you have misunderstood my question. If you query the code I share, the answer will be the table I showed (nothing new - 2 columns (region, orders), no change of request). Next time I'll show the expected result in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a common table expression (CTE) that contains all country codes and theirs corresponding region, then join it with your data.

```
WITH regions AS 
( 
            SELECT CAST('PT,IT,ES,PL,AD' AS VARCHAR) AS country_codes, 'SWE' AS region_code
  UNION ALL SELECT CAST('MD,BG,BA,SI,HR,ME,RO,RS' AS VARCHAR) AS country_codes, 'SEE' AS region_code
  UNION ALL SELECT CAST('CI,GH,MA,NG,UG,KE,TN' AS VARCHAR) AS country_codes, 'AFRICA' AS region_code
  UNION ALL SELECT CAST('CI,GH,NG,UG,KE,TN' AS VARCHAR) AS country_codes, 'SSA' AS region_code
  UNION ALL SELECT CAST('UA,BY,GE,KZ,KG,AM' AS VARCHAR) AS country_codes, 'ECA' AS region_code
)
SELECT 
    regions.region_code AS region,
    COUNT(DISTINCT orderid) AS amount_of_orders
FROM country  
     INNER JOIN regions ON STRPOS(regions.country_codes, country.country_code) > 0
GROUP BY regions.region_code;
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/101807

Answer (score 0):

You want to concatenate strings. For the lack of some CONCAT_WS function skipping nulls, just have a comma with every region and trim the string accordingly in the end.

```
SELECT
  TRIM(',' FROM
    CASE WHEN country_code IN ('PT','IT','ES','PL','AD') THEN ',SWE' ELSE '' END ||
    CASE WHEN country_code IN ('MD','BG','BA','SI','HR','ME','RO','RS') THEN ',SEE' ELSE '' END ||
    CASE WHEN country_code IN ('CI','GH','MA','NG','UG','KE','TN') THEN ',AFRICA' ELSE '' END ||
    CASE WHEN country_code IN ('CI','GH','NG','UG','KE','TN') THEN ',SSA' ELSE '' END ||
    CASE WHEN country_code IN ('UA','BY','GE','KZ','KG','AM') THEN ',ECA' ELSE '' END
  ) AS regions,
  COUNT(DISTINCT orderid) AS amount_of_orders
FROM country
GROUP BY regions
ORDER BY regions;
```

### UPDATE

You have complete changed your request. You answered that you want a column with a region list (e.g. 'AFRICA,SSA'), but now you show that you want one row per single region. Please don't make such fundamental changes to your requests. However, you want a union of single region queries now:

```
SELECT 'SWE' AS region, COUNT(DISTINCT orderid) AS amount_of_orders
FROM country
WHERE country_code IN ('PT','IT','ES','PL','AD')
UNION ALL    
SELECT 'SEE' AS region, COUNT(DISTINCT orderid) AS amount_of_orders
FROM country
WHERE country_code IN ('MD','BG','BA','SI','HR','ME','RO','RS')
UNION ALL    
SELECT 'AFRICA' AS region, COUNT(DISTINCT orderid) AS amount_of_orders
FROM country
WHERE country_code IN ('CI','GH','MA','NG','UG','KE','TN')
UNION ALL    
SELECT 'SSA' AS region, COUNT(DISTINCT orderid) AS amount_of_orders
FROM country
WHERE country_code IN ('CI','GH','NG','UG','KE','TN')
UNION ALL    
SELECT 'ECA' AS region, COUNT(DISTINCT orderid) AS amount_of_orders
FROM country
WHERE country_code IN ('UA','BY','GE','KZ','KG','AM');
```